# How to change JQuery button hover over text color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using following css to have different color when hover over. ".ui-button-text" is working fine and shows the right color when the modal shows up but button hover over is not working.

```
.ui-button-text {
    color: #7a7d7e;
}

.ui-button-text ui-state-hover {
    color: black;
}
```

**Script**

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: "auto",
            width: "auto",
            modal: true,
            title: 'Cancelling Back Order Item',
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    return true;
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

Here is the jsfiddle;

http://jsfiddle.net/7yukbsfe/1/

Comment: You missed a ' . ' here.
`.ui-button-text ui-state-hover {
    color: black;
}` . 
also creating a fiddle will be helpful.

Comment: creating a fiddle will be helpful to understand your query. thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7yukbsfe/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS is too ambiguous and is missing the target.

Use:

```
.ui-dialog button.ui-button.ui-state-hover .ui-button-text {
  color: black;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/zfqs6wac/

The `ui-state-hover` class is applied to the parent of the `.ui-button-text`.

Answer (score 2):

You might use the CSS `:hover` selector by changing your CSS to:

```
.ui-button-text {
    color: #7a7d7e;
}

.ui-button-text:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it.

Comment: @user1263981: Can you tell me please, what error message is thrown in your webbrowser console?

Answer (score 0):

You could just add `:hover` instead of `.ui-state-hover`.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattcroak/vu90qr4y/2/).

Comment: jQuery UI automatically adds the class in a hover state so that pseudo classes do not have to be used. OP is trying to make use of this.